# Why "orders" NOT ("have ordered"/ "ordered")

Tags: present-tense, headline-english

I have read this title

> Pakistan top court orders immediate release of ex-PM Imran Khan.

Why they have written "orders" in present simple? I mean why not in present perfect or simple past?

Answer (score 2):

It is a style for news headlines. Any news is relevant for only a short period of time. Putting a headline in the past tense makes the reader feel like the news is outdated before ever reading the article.

You still could use past tense, but present and past tense are [considered correct](https://www.wikihow.com/Write-a-Newspaper-Headline) when talking about news which is currently breaking.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).